# How to set the pie chart slices' border color in achartengine?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am looking fo a way to set a border color for the slices of the pie chart made with the AChartEngine Android library. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with inbuilt functions of `achartengine` .

But you can achieve this by editting library of `achartengine` .

Make following changes in `PieChart.java` class .See  `//new line added`

```
 if (seriesRenderer.isHighlighted()) {
        double rAngle = Math.toRadians(90 - (currentAngle + angle / 2));
        float translateX = (float) (radius * 0.1 * Math.sin(rAngle));
        float translateY = (float) (radius * 0.1 * Math.cos(rAngle));
        oval.offset(translateX, translateY);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, currentAngle, angle, true, paint);
        oval.offset(-translateX, -translateY);
      } else {
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);   //new line added
        canvas.drawArc(oval, currentAngle, angle, true, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  //new line added
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);  //new line added
        canvas.drawArc(oval, currentAngle, angle, true, paint); //new line added
      }
```

Comment: In what clause should I add those lines of code? 

I also don't have the sources? How can I recover them? Thanks!